# Select id and display Name

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have this array:

```
colors = [ { "id": 0, "name": "red" }, { "id": 1, "name": "blue" }, { "id": 2, "name": "green" } ]
```

I want to display select menu in vuetify and set the Id value.

I use this ;

```
<v-select
    v-for="cin colors"
    :items="colors"
    v-model="color.id"
    label="tag"
    item-text="id"
    outlined
    dense
>
</v-select>
```

this is a Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianczech/f3c54tsr/8/

So I display id and set Id , If I change item-text for name, it set name .
How can I do ?

Comment: I didn't totally get the question but maybe this little change help you https://jsfiddle.net/n9L2pa3o/

Comment: I want to have name on the select screen. When a choose for example green , it set  the id and not the name.

Comment: use `item-text="name"` and `item-value="id"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use item-text and item-value to split the values and label:

```
 <v-select
   :items="colors"
   item-text="name"
   item-value="id"
   v-model="selectedValue"
   label="color"
   >
</v-select>
```

DATA:

```
  data() {
    return {
      selectedValue: '',
        colors: [ { "id": 0, "name": "red" }, { "id": 1, "name": "blue" }, { "id": 2, "name": "green" } ]
     }
   }
```